# Extract minimum and maximum year from string in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that I read into a Pandas DataFrame that contains a column with multiple year values separated by a semicolon.

I need to extract the minimum and maximum value from the string and save each in a new column.

I am able to print the minimum and maximum but I can't seem to get the correct values from each row saved into a new column.

Any help is much appreciated.

Sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'id': ['1473-2262', '2327-9214', '1949-8349', '2375-6314', 
                   '0095-6562'],
            'years': ['2000; 2001; 2002; 2003; 2004; 2004; 2004; 2005', 
                      '2003; 2004; 2005', '2015', np.nan, '2012; 2014']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'years'])
```

This is the DataFrame that I need:

```
          id                                           years  minyear  maxyear
0  1473-2262  2000; 2001; 2002; 2003; 2004; 2004; 2004; 2005   2000.0   2005.0
1  2327-9214                                2003; 2004; 2005   2003.0   2005.0
2  1949-8349                                            2015   2015.0   2015.0
3  2375-6314                                             NaN      NaN      NaN
4  0095-6562                                      2012; 2014   2012.0   2014.0
```

I can print the minimum and maximum:

```
x = df['years'].notnull()

for row in df['years'][x].str.split(pat=';'):
    lst = list()
    for item in row:
        lst.append(int(item))
    print('Min=',min(lst),'Max=',max(lst))

Min= 2000 Max= 2005
Min= 2003 Max= 2005
Min= 2015 Max= 2015
Min= 2012 Max= 2014
```

Here's how I've tried to capture the values to new columns:

```
x = df['years'].notnull()

for row in df['years'][x].str.split(pat=';'):
    lst = list()
    for item in row:
        lst.append(int(item))
    df['minyear']=min(lst)
    df['maxyear']=max(lst)
```

Only the values from the last row are saved to the new columns.

```
              id                                           years  minyear  maxyear
0  1473-2262  2000; 2001; 2002; 2003; 2004; 2004; 2004; 2005     2012     2014
1  2327-9214                                2003; 2004; 2005     2012     2014
2  1949-8349                                            2015     2012     2014
3  2375-6314                                             NaN     2012     2014
4  0095-6562                                      2012; 2014     2012     2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for new `DataFrame`, then cast to `float`.

Index values are same, so assign new columns:

```
df1 = df['years'].str.split('; ', expand=True).astype(float)
df = df.assign(maxyear=df1.max(axis=1),minyear=df1.min(axis=1))
#same as
#df['maxyear'], df['minyear'] = df1.min(axis=1), df1.max(axis=1)
print (df)
          id                                           years  maxyear  minyear
0  1473-2262  2000; 2001; 2002; 2003; 2004; 2004; 2004; 2005   2000.0   2005.0
1  2327-9214                                2003; 2004; 2005   2003.0   2005.0
2  1949-8349                                            2015   2015.0   2015.0
3  2375-6314                                             NaN      NaN      NaN
4  0095-6562                                      2012; 2014   2012.0   2014.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution similar to the one proposed by jezrael, but using a conversion to a Series. **Warning**: This solution does not scale well.

```
years = df.years.str.split(";").apply(pd.Series).astype(float)        
#0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
#0  2000.0  2001.0  2002.0  2003.0  2004.0  2004.0  2004.0  2005.0
#1  2003.0  2004.0  2005.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
#2  2015.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
#3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
#4  2012.0  2014.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
df['maxyear'], df['minyear'] = years.min(axis=1), years.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: My solution is only twice as slow as your. Not too bad :)

Comment: Nope, just 5. Wouldn't it scale linearly with the number of rows?

Comment: Hard question, really dont know answer.